# How to set up Mosquitto MQTT broker on a shared server?

Tags: server, mqtt, mosquitto

Is it possible to run the Mosquitto Broker on any shared server? The closest solution I got to is this [here](https://blog.benjamin-cabe.com/2015/10/01/how-to-run-your-web-server-and-mqtt-websockets-broker-on-the-same-port), it only tells how to configure it, but I can't figure out how to install it on my server without ssh.

Another possible solution for my problem will be to use hosted brokers like [CloudMQTT](https://www.cloudmqtt.com). I don't like it's plans and pricing, are there any other alternatives to this?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by shared server? Do you mean a virtual host on a webserver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have console (SSH) access to the machine to install and run software it is going to be very difficult to add a broker without help from the administrator.

If you do mean a virtual host on a shared web server, then this is unlikely to happen as there is no concept of virtual hosts for MQTT so each user would have to be given their own port number (may be 2 if you want MQTT over websockets)